# A creature or beast?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

Below the ground and in the air,
You can find a creature hiding there.
Above you now, not found below,
Indeed before, before any go.

After now it will hide away,
Never in a day does it stay.
Missing only once in all.
Changed appearance! Now don't fall.

Hint 1:

> [This Finding](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/30276/9951)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is:

> I

Below the ground and in the air,
You can find a creature hiding there.

> **i** is hiding in the word 'air'

Above you now, not found below,

> the italic *I* is right above the answer text field, but not below.

Indeed before, before any go.

> Indeed starts with "i"

After now it will hide away,

> **i** hiding in the word 'it'

Never in a day does it stay.

> **i** is not in the word 'day'

Missing only once in all.

> All lines contains the letter i or ! except line 3 (edited with OP's hint)

Changed appearance! Now don't fall.

> ! is upside down of i (appearance changed), don't fall!

Comment: Extremely close. You pretty much have it. It's only one of the two you listed though. Also, only missing once in all does not refer to the word all. Perhaps missing once in 8...

Comment: Ahh I can't figure it out!  give me some time =D

Comment: You had a good catch with your last line.

Comment: Pretty close, but not quite. The answer is only half of what you listed. I think if you look at it that way, the other's will fall right in.

Comment: Ohhhh, it's only 'i', let me fill in the reasoning~~~

Comment: Well done. Might want to change one though. 3rd line does not contain the answer, where the last does if you count the changed appearance.

Answer (score 3):

I would say it's a

> Vampire

**1st stanza**

> They sleep in coffins and can turn into bats

**2nd stanza**

> They become dust when hit by daylight

Comment: Nice attempt, but no. There are several clues that don't fit with this.

Answer (score 3):

My idea : Are you

> the night ?

Below the ground and in the air,
You can find a creature hiding there.

> Night is everywhere, even in the air

Above you now, not found below,
Indeed before, before any go.

> I think that below the ground is the other side of the Earth. At the begining the night is on the other side, but when it is here it is not on the other side anymore

After now it will hide away,
Never in a day does it stay.

> Obviously night does not stay during a day

Missing only once in all.
Changed appearance! Now don't fall.

> ??? Not sure about this one

Comment: Definitely a good attempt, but as with the last line, it doesn't quite fit.

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer, but an idea:

> Below "the ground" and above "you now" are the words "find a", which cannot be found below. Unfortunately, I can't seem to make a creature from it.

Comment: Titles are not always direct clues.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is:

> The Moon

Below the ground and in the air,

You can find a creature hiding there.

> The moon can be overhead or on the otherside of the earth

Above you now, not found below,

Indeed before, before any go.

> If it's overhead it isn't on the otherside of the earth

After now it will hide away,

Never in a day does it stay.

> It will be on the otherside of the earth within 24 hours

Missing only once in all.

> Missing due to eclipses which are rare.

Changed appearance! Now don't fall.

> Looks brighter and closer on full moons, but if it got too close and fell to the earth we would all die.

Comment: Another good attempt, but no. Missing the "Indeed before, before any go".